# GetWindowThreadProcessID() returns different results based on context

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cmd

I am experiencing a problem of [GetWindowThreadProcessID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returning different results based on where it is called from, even if the window parameter is the same.

One situation where it happening is when I am running Shell Hook in command prompt (cmd.exe). The window is created by the "cmd.exe" but the shell hook is running in the "conhost.exe":

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ShellCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  if (nCode == HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED)
  {
    DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessID((HWND)wParam, NULL);
    // tid will be a thread of conhost.exe
  }
}
```

If I call same GetWindowThreadProcessID() function from any other program, giving the same Window handle, I get a thread ID of the cmd.exe process.

If I inspect the window in question with Spy++, I get the thread ID and process ID of the "cmd.exe" - results consistent of running GetWindowThreadProcessID() from any other app.

Shouldn't the GetWindowThreadProcessID() function return same thread ID regardless what context it was called from? Is there a way to know if code is hitting this situation, where returned thread id is of the hosting process?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, the OS maintains the illusion that the console window is owned by the process that created it.  But no point in creating that illusion inside conhost.exe, it is supposed to know.  You'll have to deal with this.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: @HansPassant: that's curious, come to think of it.  I wonder what happens if the original `cmd.exe` exits?  Does GetWindowThreadProcessId() keep pointing at it, or at one of the other processes running in the same console?  If there's more than one, how does it choose which one?  I suppose it is best to make no assumptions about what GetWindowThreadProcessId() will return for a console window.  Better still not to even try to obtain a handle to the console window; I suspect it's abnormal in more ways than one.

Comment: GetConsoleWindow() is a pretty wise way to get the handle :)